# Question about PlayAnimMontage code in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a question about the implementation of the method PlayAnimMontage (class ACharacter). [Here](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/ACharacter/PlayAnimMontage/index.html) is the API information.

I'm trying to understand the code. This method call Montage_Play() before Montage_JumpToSection(). 
This is the code:

```
float ACharacter::PlayAnimMontage(class UAnimMontage* AnimMontage, float InPlayRate, FName StartSectionName)
{
    UAnimInstance * AnimInstance = (Mesh) ? Mesh->GetAnimInstance() : nullptr;
    if (AnimMontage && AnimInstance)
    {
        float const Duration = AnimInstance->Montage_Play(AnimMontage, InPlayRate);

        if (Duration > 0.f)
        {
            // Start at a given Section.
            if (StartSectionName != NAME_None)
            {
                AnimInstance->Montage_JumpToSection(StartSectionName, AnimMontage);
            }

            return Duration;
        }
    }

    return 0.f;
}
```

I'm so confused. Why if I play the animation, I can specify the specific section later???
I know it works, but, I don't understand.
Can anyone help me please??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this line is called,

```
AnimInstance->Montage_Play(AnimMontage, InPlayRate);
```

The animation montage passed in starts playing. However, this next line,

```
AnimInstance->Montage_JumpToSection(StartSectionName, AnimMontage);
```

jumps the animation montage to a certain section. The reason why `Montage_Play` is called before `Montage_JumpToSection` is because there's no way to play an animation montage starting at a certain section with one function. Therefore, the consecutive calls of `Montage_Play`, then `Montage_JumpToSection` simulate the playing of an animation montage starting at `StartSectionName`. Note that `Montage_JumpToSection` will only work when the animation montage is currently in the playback stage. To check if an animation montage is currently being played, you can pass the montage into `Montage_GetCurrentSection` to check which section the montage is currently in.

Comment: So, it starts with first section but I can’t appreciate it because of the code velocity? That’s explains the cause when I comment Montage_JumpToSection(...) it plays the first one. Am I right? Thanks for answer! :)

Comment: @AlejandrodelaPlataRamos That is correct. And no problem, if you found the answer helpful, please consider upvoting or accepting it. Good luck coding!